# How can I transform 2022M01 to date format as 2022/01/01?

Tags: r, date, format

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(Destí = c("Total industria", "Total industria", 
"Total industria", "Total industria", "Total industria", "Total industria"
), Unitat = c("Índex", "Índex", "Índex", "Índex", "Índex", 
"Índex"), Data = c("2023M02", "2023M01", "2022M12", "2022M11", 
"2022M10", "2022M09"), Valor = c(104.409, 100.976, 98.037, 109.411, 
110.424, 109.138), Territori = c("Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I need to transform the column `Data` (character) to date format. Now it appears as `2022M01` and I need to be `2022/01/01`

So far, I have tried: `IPI_ESP$Data <- lubridate::parse_date_time(IPI_ESP$Data, orders = c("%YM%m", "%m/%Y"))` But I only get NA values.

Comment: Does M stand for month? So you have date values with just year and month, no day of month?

Comment: Something like `df %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(sub("M", "-", paste0(Data, "-01"))))`?

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time(IPI_ESP$Data, "Ym")` works for me.